# problems with the class-path manifest file setting

Tags: java

My file structure looks like this:

```
manifest
CP.java
folder/
    X.java
```

CP is a class which simply prints out `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`.

`manifest` is:

```
Main-Class: CP
Class-Path: folder
```

I make a jar with:

```
$ jar cvfm x.jar manifest CP.class
```

Now, the problem is shown:

```
$ java -jar x.jar
x.jar
```

How can I make the output

```
x.jar:folder
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The Class-Path header is intended to load classes from other jars from within your jar file.

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

I think your "folder" manifest addition is just dropped because it doesn't conform with specifications ([jar tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)).

Comment: How can I get my desired result then? `java -cp` doesn't work on jars.

Comment: What exactly is your desired result? Could you just include X.class in the CP.class jar, or create another jar with X.class and load that in your manifest?